# Throttle ASP.NET Web Api with ActionFilterAttribute extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am attempting to add a usage throttle to my Web Api application. However, the custom attribute is not being implemented.

**Custom Attribute**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Caching;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyApp.Filters
{
    public enum TimeUnit
    {
        Minute = 60,
        Hour = 3600,
        Day = 86400
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class ThrottleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public TimeUnit TimeUnit { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    public class GetUsersController : ApiController
    {
        [Throttle(TimeUnit = TimeUnit.Minute, Count = 5)]
        [Throttle(TimeUnit = TimeUnit.Hour, Count = 20)]
        [Throttle(TimeUnit = TimeUnit.Day, Count = 100)]
        public ICollection<Users> Get(int id)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Am I way off? Implementing the attribute incorrectly? Extending the wrong attribute? I know that I'm using `System.Web.Mvc` instead of `System.Web.Http.Filters`... but all of the resources I've seen have called for exactly that. Maybe you have a better answer? :)

Comment: Out of curiosity - why are you doing this? What are your requirements? Because if it relates to system resources being used - there are more efficient ways of throttling in this regard a lot earlier in the pipeline. The action filters are relatively 'late' compared to other options.

Comment: Honestly, because it's what I've found that other people have done. If you have a better way for implementing throttling, please let me know.

Also, this app is pretty old, .NET framework 4.5 and WebApi 4.0 - so I've tried using a couple nuget packages for throttling but it tries to update the whole app for a later version of WebApi and throws everything else off.

Comment: That's fair, but I mean why are you doing it? Why are you throttling in the first place? Are you throttling to control usage of your service by your consumers, or is it more to protect your system resource against excessive work?

Comment: My manager is worried that people are going to write loops and be trying to constantly send requests to the API (potentially bogging down the server and what not). I'm under the impression that (unless the end users are really being jerks), it would be single threaded so that shouldn't be an issue. But it's something the managers want.

Comment: Please post the code inside your override function.  Maybe you are forgetting to call `base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext)`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling `base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext)` at some point in your code.  If you are using .NET Standard (don't know about Core) then you should also remember to register your filter in App_Start\FilterConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    //add this part
    filters.Add(new ThrottleAttribute());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you're using `ActionFilterAttribute` from `System.Web.Mvc`, instead of from `System.Web.Http.Filters`, as you've mentioned in your question.

MVC filters will only be executed for a controller as part of the MVC lifecycle. The same goes for HTTP filters for API controllers. That means your attribute should look like this instead:

```
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

public class ThrottleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    // Note the different signature to what you have in your question.
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

If you now put a breakpoint on that method, and make a call to your API controller, it should hit it.

If you want to use your existing filter for an MVC controller, that will work just fine.